# Is there a way to rewrite these URLs?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is there a way to get accessible all images in the folder:

```
www.example.com/image/
```

through URL like this:

```
static.example.com/image/
```

For instance, the image

```
www.example.com/image/hello.jpg
```

is accessible only through:

```
static.example.com/image/hello.jpg
```

Comment: You mean via some subdomain?

Comment: You could generate rewrite -s (with status code 301 preferably), is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a virtual name host for `static.example.com` and `Alias` /image/ to the directory you want.

Then set up a `<Location>` section in the virtual host for `www.example.com` and `Deny` access to it.

Comment: Can I do this only with htaccess ?

Comment: No. Virtual hosts can't be configured on a per-directory basis. You need to put it in the main configuration.

Comment: I haven't permission to do that, I am on a shared hosting :(

Comment: @xRobot You should have some sort of control panel on shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already created the subdomain: `static.example.com`.

On `www.example.com` host, enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(image(?:/.*|))$ http://static.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```